# JS Regular Expressions split

Tags: javascript, regex

this is my text '123,456/,789,ABC' and I want to split by ',' but not split '/,'.

```
var text = '123,456/,789,ABC';
var texts = text.split(/[^/],/g);
console.log(texts)
```

result is [ '12', '456/,78', 'ABC' ]

but I expect [ '123', '456/,789', 'ABC' ]

Comment: Why the need for regex here? text.split(',') should be sufficient.

Comment: @Antiga but that would split '456/' and '789' when he wants '456/,789'

Comment: @RockOnRockOut Right you are. I misread. I was going by his question where he said wanted to split by just the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*?[^\/]),|(.+?)$
```

This will work the way you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oO8zI4/6

Comment: This works – note that you need to use `text.match(/REGEX/g)` rather than `text.split(/REGEX/g)`, because this regex matches the content between the commas, rather than the commas themselves.

Comment: You could still use split, just need to check the elements in the resulting array. This is what it produces:["", "123", undefined, "", "456/,789", undefined, "", undefined, "ABC", ""], so ignore undefined and empty strings

Comment: @Shai - actually, the result of using `match` still includes the commas in the array values:  `["123,", "456/,789,", "ABC"]`

Comment: Yes. So you need to either use this with `split` and remove empty matches (which may not be acceptable if empty entries in the original string need to be preserved), or with `match` and remove trailing commas. All because of JS's lack of lookbehind - I wonder whether regex is more trouble than it's worth in this case

Comment: yes, this is ok. So I can use underscore _.compact() to clean up unuse data.

Answer (score 3):

For your situation you can simply use this regexp:

```
var text = '123,456/,789,ABC';
var texts = text.split(/\b,/g);
console.log(texts); // ["123", "456/,789", "ABC"]
```

The idea is that word boundary metacharacter `\b,` will not match `/,` because backslash is not word character, so there is no word boundary between `/` and `,`.

#### RegExp test: http://regex101.com/r/qB6aT7/1